# Datagrid for flex mobile

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.6

I've seen many posts on using datagrid for flex mobile apps and the performance issues that comes with it.

I wish i could get those performance issues because my problem is that i can't even see the datagrid component in my component list, only list, datagroup e.t.c

I have tried to uncheck the "Only show recemmended component" but i still cant find it in the component list. But when i create a flex project (not mobile), i see it. But then, i want to use it in a mobile project.
This will be my first mobile app. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about write below code? Of course, you can add component at source view also. Not only can it by using design view and component list.

```
<s:DataGrid id="grid" width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="name" headerText="Name"/>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="age" headerText="Age"/>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

As far as I remember, it can use DataGrid in mobile project without any special settings.